# Using dgrid/dstore's REST store with a filter

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I would like to extend dstore/Rest to take a parameter that is used to filter the store.  This article suggests this is the desired method to alter the query of a dstore: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/11/17/introducing-dstore/

Example:

```js
new MyExtendedRestStore({color: 'red'});
```

I would like the internals of MyExtendedRestStore to alter the GET query so that color would now be set in the filter so any refresh calls would stick to adding color=red to the query.  If I understand this correctly, it should also force the dstore/Trackable mixin to obey the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dgrid 0.4, instances using `OnDemandList` or `Pagination` can accept any collection - whether it be a root store, or a collection generated as a result of performing operations on that store.  `filter` is one such operation.

In your case you state you want the grid to always show only red items, so you could very easily pass the grid a filtered collection, and no custom extension of `Rest` is required:

```
var TrackableRestStore = declare([ Rest, Trackable ]);
var store = new TrackableRestStore({ target: '...' });
var filteredCollection = store.filter({ color: 'red' });
var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
    collection: filteredCollection,
    columns: ...
});
```

This is also discussed towards the end of dgrid's [Grids and Stores tutorial](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/).

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to hitch that to "refresh"?

Comment: `refresh` is going to re-read from the assigned collection.  If you assign a collection that is the result of filtering a store, that filter will always apply when the grid refreshes, sorts, etc.  Is that what you mean?